# Detailed gravity maps

Tags: satellites, gravity

Does anyone know if it is possible to get a gravity map of a specific region of Greenland? 
The data I've found here http://icgem.gfz-potsdam.de/vis3d/longtime , are simply of to low spatial resolution. I need to get it down to Sentinel-2 levels. Around 10-60 meters pr. pixel.
I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use GOCE USER TOOLBOX to produce a gravity anomaly map with GOCE data.

Comment: I really doubt that gravity data over Greenland exists at 60m resolutions. That sounds like a ridiculously high resolution for gravity data.